# Why does my url contain 2x www.?

Tags: url, dns

We have pointed our domain to a WIX server using the appropriate A Name record changes.

However, when we call up our site - zimmeracht.com or www.zimmeracht.com - the URL changes to www.www.zimmeracht.com.

Has any body experienced this before? Any ideas how we can change this? A DNS problem @WIX perhaps?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check there is no subdomain WWW.

Also check the WWW record is an A record to the same IP as the @ record.

It appears you are not alone and is an issue with Wix: http://www.wix.com/support/forum/flash/about-wix/other/help-double-wwwwww-on-my-site

This issue occurs when your domain is not pointing to Wix correctly, according to the instructions provided.

"If your domain is managed elsewhere, and pointing to Wix using A records, please make sure that you have added the records according to our instructions here.

Note: We do not recommend using the pointing method, rather we suggest pointing your domain's name servers to Wix's name servers (NS1.WIX.COM and NS2.WIX.COM).

Note: Many Internet Service Providers (ISP) cache their DNS records and update them once every 3 days. Therefore if you have pointed to Wix using name servers within the last 72 hours, and you are still experiencing this issue, please allow the changes 72 hours to propagate before trying again. "

http://www.wix.com/support/forum/html5/domains-emails-and-my-account/connecting-my-domain-to-wix/double-wwwwww

If the above advice doesnt help I recommend contacting Wix support as it may be a issue specific to them.

Comment: I'm currently trying to move FROM wix and I'm getting www.www., I removed all DNS entries at my domain provider and pointed all to them locally. BAM – getting www.www. now.

Comment: I would try removing any www a record, it is possible wix applies them automatically

Comment: I found the issue. I had the WIX DNS still associated with my hoster... Didn't find it since the domain belongs to the other hoster and I completely deleted any forwards. So I think it was some update-time related issue with all DNS around the world. Git it now, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is contradicting response

"This issue occurs when your domain is not pointing to Wix correctly, according to the instructions provided."

with

" Note: Many Internet Service Providers (ISP) cache their DNS records and update them once every 3 days. Therefore if you have pointed to Wix using name servers within the last 72 hours, and you are still experiencing this issue, please allow the changes 72 hours to propagate before trying again. "

Comment: I was providing a possible alternative cause

Answer (score -2):

Possibly u r using shared ip on wix